# AWS S3 static website buckets routing per subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting, amazon-route53

I have created a hosted zone: "abc.com" and 2 s3 buckets: "app1.abc.com" and "app2.abc.com" with respective index.html. I am able to accesss individual default s3 website successfully (ex: app1.abc.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com and app2.abc.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com)

Now, How to create record sets to redirect traffic lets say if "app1.abc.com" called, then index.html of "app1.abc.com" bucket should be accessed. If "app2.abc.com" called, then index.html of "app2.abc.com" bucket should be accessed.

Is it possible to do with s3 and route53? If not any other ways to redirect traffic based on url to s3 bucket?

I went through documentation but no clue. Appreciate for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to create a CNAME record that point `app1.abc.com` to `app1.abc.com.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com`. The procedure is the same for the second bucket.

For documentation, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs

Comment: Thankyou. I have edited my question little. I am not majorily worried about www.app.abc.com to app.abc.com but about suddomain traffic routing to respective buckets. these 2 buckets have different application code. if user need "app1", need to hit "app1.abc.com" respectively for app2. I am struck with subdomain routing.

Comment: @Forece85 I have updated the answer. The original question really emphasized the www part. And the fact that there are two buckets is not relevant to this problem. Just repeat the solution for the second bucket.